# Otimização de Código / Processamento de Imagem

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade em C sobre processamento de imagens.
E preciso achar uma alternativa para otimizar um determinado trecho do código. Eis aqui:

```
/* Backward Rotina */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        for (altura = img->altura - 2; altura >= 0; altura--)
        {
            for (largura = img->largura - 2; largura >= 0; largura--)
            {

                if (aux->dados[0][altura][largura] != 0)
                {
                    if (   aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura + 1] != 0
                        && aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura + 1] < aux->dados[0][altura][largura])
                    {
                        out->dados[0][altura][largura] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura + 1];
                    }
                    else if (   aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura] != 0
                             && aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura] < aux->dados[0][altura][largura])
                    {
                        out->dados[0][altura][largura] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura];
                    }
                    else if (   aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura - 1] != 0
                             && aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura - 1] < aux->dados[0][altura][largura])
                    {
                        out->dados[0][altura][largura] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura - 1];
                    }
                    else if (   aux->dados[0][altura][largura + 1] != 0
                             && aux->dados[0][altura][largura + 1] < aux->dados[0][altura][largura])
                    {
                        out->dados[0][altura][largura] = aux->dados[0][altura][largura + 1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
/* ================================================================================================================================ */
```

---

## Funcionamento

O funcionamento é no algoritmo *multi-pass*, varrendo a matriz da imagem verificando a vizinhança. Para a etapa *foward* verifica-se os vizinhos acima e a esquerda indo dos index `[1,1] < [X,Y]`, para o *backward* os vizinhos da direita e inferior indo de `[X-2,Y-2] > [0,0]`. Ignorando as bordas pois não são confiáveis.
Segue imagem de exemplificação:
[image: Multi-pass processo]

---

## O que fazer?

Preciso achar uma forma de otimizar este aninhado imenso de `if/else`, que de acordo o professor há melhores maneiras de fazer.
Estou a mais de duas horas arrancando os cabelos pensando em uma solução, mas até o momento não consegui chegar a uma solução que fosse mais viável e com um menor custo computacional, todas as rotas me levam a aninhados de `if/else`.

---

## Edit

*Resultado rotina Foward:*
[image: Foward]

Após o Foward executa a Rotina Backward.

*Resultado Rotina Backward:*
[image: Backward]

Comment: Para entender, o algoritmo precisa colocar em `out->dados[0][altura][largura]` um dos vizinhos a "sudoeste", "sul", "sudeste" e "leste" (assumindo que a altura cresce para o "sul" e a largura cresce para o "leste"), o primeiro que for menor que o valor atual, procurando na ordem "sudeste"->"sul"->"sudoeste"->"leste", contanto que nenhum valor desses seja zero. Estou certo? O que significa o valor zero?

Comment: Correto, o valor zero significa que aquele componente é um fundo, e deve ser ignorado. Tudo que for diferente de zero é um elemento de imagem que está interligado, essa alteração por um valor menor significa que este ponto está interligado e são um mesmo componente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gostaria primeiramente de agradecer a ajuda de todos, @Lacobus, @Renan e @Wtrmute.

Após analisar as sugestões dadas por todos, utilizando um pedacinho de cada uma montei o código da seguinte forma:

```
    /* Backward Rotine */
    for (altura = img->altura - 2; altura > 0; altura--)
    {
        for (largura = img->largura - 2; largura > 0; largura--)
        {

            if ((pixel = out->dados[0][altura][largura]) == 0) continue;

            vizinho[0] = out->dados[0][altura + 1][largura + 1];
            vizinho[1] = out->dados[0][altura + 1][largura];
            vizinho[2] = out->dados[0][altura + 1][largura - 1];
            vizinho[3] = out->dados[0][altura][largura + 1];

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if(vizinho[i] < pixel && vizinho[i] != 0)
                {
                    out->dados[0][altura][largura] = vizinho[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Obrigado pessoal!
Utilizando o código dessa forma percebi um ganho de performance considerável, diminuindo em quase 3 segundos a execução da rotina completa em algumas imagens.

Answer (score 5):

Segue uma outra solução usando um mapeamento "estático" das coordenadas dos vizinhos:

```
int masc[4][2] = { {1,1}, {1,0}, {1,-1}, {0,1} };

for( altura = img->altura - 2; altura >= 0; altura-- )
{
    for( largura = img->largura - 2; largura >= 0; largura-- )
    {
        if( aux->dados[0][altura][largura] != 0 )
        {
            for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
            {
                if( (aux->dados[0][altura + masc[i][0]][largura + masc[i][1]] != 0) &&
                    (aux->dados[0][altura + masc[i][0]][largura + masc[i][1]] < aux->dados[0][altura][largura]))
                {
                    out->dados[0][altura][largura] = aux->dados[0][altura + masc[i][0]][largura + masc[i][1]];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Embora eu ache que minha resposta está correta, [a do Lacobus está melhor, mais concisa e é mais eficiente.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212829/1658)

```
/* Backward Rotina */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
int[] vizinhos = int[4];
for (altura = img->altura - 2; altura >= 0; altura--)
{
    for (largura = img->largura - 2; largura >= 0; largura--)
    {
        vizinhos[0] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura + 1];
        vizinhos[1] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura];
        vizinhos[2] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura - 1];
        vizinhos[3] = aux->dados[0][altura][largura + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int valorVizinho = vizinhos[i];
            if (valorVizinho != 0 && valorVizinho < aux->dados[0][altura][largura])
            {
                aux->dados[0][altura][largura] = valorVizinho;
                break; // Eis o pulo do gato
            }
        }
    }
}
/* ================================================================================================================================ */
```

E sim, eu sei que talvez você tenha que usar `alloc`, `malloc`, `calloc` para declarar o vetor `vizinhos`, e talvez até usar ponteiro para acessar as posições. Eu quis só dar a ideia aqui. Eu estou mais enferrujado em C do que casco de naufrágio.

Se você fizer uma referência para `aux->dados[0]`, i.e.: ponto, algo como:

```
int* ponto = &aux->dados[0];
```

...você consegue encurtar ainda mais o código, pois ao invés de:

```
vizinhos[0] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura + 1];
```

...você poderia escrever:

```
vizinhos[0] = ponto[altura + 1][largura + 1];
```

...O que facilita a leitura. Mais uma vez, eu posso ter errado a sintaxe específica do C, mas essa ideia é válida em C e praticamente todas as linguagens parentes dela.

P.s.: admiro todo mundo que tem a coragem de estudar processamento de sinais. Não é uma área fácil.

Comment: Primeiramente, agradeço pela sugestão e disponibilização de tempo para me responder. Essa ideia também me ocorreu, porém levando em conta o **custo computacional**, alocar um vetor a cada iteração e executar um novo laço de repetição, mesmo com critério de parada, acaba saindo mais custoso para a máquina. A tentativa mesmo é tentar receber ideias de como otimizar e diminuir o custo, porém tudo está me levando a crer que não há outra forma :/

Comment: Entendo. Se a intenção é realmente escovar bits, vou editar a resposta para algo mais eficiente.

Comment: Uma das dificuldades aqui é o fato da rotina ser bem genérica, quase não tem muito o que se fazer, mas o professor quase que me bateu quando eu disse: *"Não achei nenhuma forma mais adequada do que essa!"*  
Dizendo ele: *"Tem, larga de preguiça e vai pensar!"*

Comment: Isso é maldade por parte do seu professor. A propósito, se escovação de bits é importante, o @Lacobus acaba de dar o que acredito ser a melhor resposta possível.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, dado o trecho de código mostrado e as características do algoritmo que consegui apreender, há algumas observações que dá pra fazer:

Primeiro, se você quiser evitar os `if`s aninhados, você pode transformar o primeiro

```
if (aux->dados[0][altura][largura] != 0) {
    /* outros ifs... */
}
```

em

```
if (aux->dados[0][altura][largura] == 0) continue;
/* outros ifs... */
```

e garantir que o pixel atual não é de fundo.

Segundo, a ideia de memoizar o pixel atual e os vizinhos, sugerida pelo Renan, não é má: você não precisa alocar um vetor novo a cada iteração, pode usar o mesmo e sobrescrever com os dados novos:

```
int pixel;
int vizinhos[4];
for (altura = img->altura - 2; altura >= 0; altura --) {
    for (largura = img->largura - 2; largura >= 0; largura --) {
        if ((pixel = aux->dados[0][altura][largura]) == 0) continue;

        vizinhos[0] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura + 1];
        vizinhos[1] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura];
        vizinhos[2] = aux->dados[0][altura + 1][largura - 1];
        vizinhos[3] = aux->dados[0][altura][largura + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
            if (vizinhos[i] < pixel) {
                out->dados[0][altura][largura] = vizinhos[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Agora, o item possivelmente mais importante é o fato de que você está conferindo os vizinhos cujas coordenadas você *já varreu*. Isso *normalmente* quer dizer que o algoritmo é feito para ser executado *in-place*, isto é, você não precisa de um *array* de resultado `out` separado do *array* de entrada `aux`. Com isso você economiza o espaço de uma imagem inteira — embora temporalmente o algoritmo continue *O(altura × largura)*.

Portanto dê uma analisada no algoritmo para ver se você realmente pode efetuar o algoritmo in-place, e possivelmente você vai ter um ganho bom de espaço e, possivelmente, muito menos *cache misses*.